# C Linux - Symbolic link of a file in the source directory

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to create a symbolic link named ./file-path(suffix) to the ./file-path in the source directory from where I search for the file.

I tried with symlink(old_path_of_file,new_path_of_file), but it doesn`t show up in the source directory.

```
void search_for_file(char *dirName,char *file,int *regasire_file,int *regasire_dir){
    struct stat *metadata;
    struct dirent *dirEntry;
    struct stat bufstat;


    int ret;
    DIR *dir;

    dir = opendir(dirName);
    if (dir==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the directory\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while ((dirEntry = readdir(dir))!=NULL){
        if (strcmp(dirEntry->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(dirEntry->d_name,"..")==0)
            continue;

        char name[1000];
        sprintf(name,"%s/%s",dirName,dirEntry->d_name);

        lstat(name,&bufstat);
        if (strcmp(dirEntry->d_name,file)==0){
            if (S_ISREG(bufstat.st_mode)){
                char path[1000];
                char new_path[1000];
                (*regasire_file)++;             
                sprintf(path,"%d",*regasire_file);
                sprintf(new_path,"%s/%s",name,path);
                int fd_dir = dirfd(dir);
                if ((symlink(dirName,new_path))==-1){
                    perror("error symlink\n");
                }


            }
            if (S_ISDIR(bufstat.st_mode)){
                (*regasire_dir)++;              
                printf("dir nr. %d \n",*regasire_dir);              
            }
        }

        if (dirEntry->d_type == DT_DIR){
            search_for_file(name,file,regasire_file,regasire_dir);
        }


    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: The symlink should appear as whatever you set in `new_path_of_file`.  Did you check the returned value of `symlink()`?  It might have failed.

Comment: Did you check the return value of symlink? See here for more information: https://linux.die.net/man/3/symlink

Comment: @cdarke how do i make it to appear in the directory I specify?

Comment: You specify it in the new path (2nd parameter).

Comment: @cdarke i still don`t get it to work. How should I use symlink() if I know all the parameters and I have to show the new created symbolic link in the source directory?

Comment: If I get your code correct you go through all entries of `dirName`. Each entry is `dirName/dirEntry->d_name`. If it's a regular file you extend the entry name by the number in `regasire_file` resulting in `{dirName}/{dirEntry->d_name}/{regasire_file}`. By the last '/' you try to create a symlink with name `regasire_file` in a subdirectory `dirName/dirEntry->d_name/`. This won't work since this directory does not exist?!